# How to add commands after functioncall inside an nnoremap map?

Tags: vim

I want to write a function in vimscript that writes a python functionbody for me and than positions my curser at the right place.

The function asks for some parameters (name of the function, its parameters, returnvalue) and than builds a string to be returned. That works fine. But after calling the function via

`nnoremap <leader>cf cc<c-r>=ProduceFunction()<cr>`

I am left in insert mode at the end of the last line inserted. So i tryed to append `<esc>3kO` to the code above, but the `<esc>` just gets passed to the function instead of beeing exectued after the function is completed. Any way to tell vim to first finish executing the function?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using some kind of snippet plugin like [Ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips), in [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zik6u0klD40) you can see some features of it.

Comment: That's a really cool plugin and I will definitely use that instead!
But i am nevertheless interested in knowing if there is a way to do it the way i originally planned